# Filter out array to get out unique values and populate a select dropdown box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have an array that is coming from an API that can contain a combination of 4 different values:

> (none, A, B, C)

That array is used to populate a select dropdown box.

When I run the web app, the drop down box(select) that looks like this in my webpage:

```
<select>
    <option value>All</option>
    <option value="A,B,C">ABC</option>
    <option value></option>
    <option value="A,C">AC</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="B,C">BC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
select>
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
<select>
    <option value>All</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

It is getting dynamically populated from state with this function in the React-Table library:

```
function SelectColumnFilter({
    column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
    // Calculate the options for filtering
    // using the preFilteredRows
    const options = React.useMemo(() => {
        const options = new Set()
        preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
            options.add(row.values[id])
        })
        return [...options.values()]
    }, [id, preFilteredRows])
    console.log("SelectColumnFilter: ", options);
```

When I write out the options to the console, here is what I see:

```
0: (3) ["A", "B", "C"]
1: (0) []
2: (2) ["A", "C"
3: (1) ["B"]
4: (2) ["B", "C"]
5: (1) ["C"]
```

So since I know that there are only 4 possible values, All, A, B, and C that I want to have in my select control, I was wondering if there's a way to filter out the option arrays to only show each unique value so that it looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option value>All</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check in your `forEach`, and create a temporary array first, then return a `Set` to make it unique:

```
let tempArr = [];
preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
    if(row.values[id].length == 1) tempArr.push(row.values[id][0])
})
return [...new Set(tempArr)]
```

And you can add a default option for value `All` or `None`, whichever is the case

Comment: that cleaned it up a bit. The option values now look like this: All, A, A, B, B, C...

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Edited answer. Note that you need to push the element, not the array (`row.values[id][0]`)

Comment: Hi thanks, it now looks like : All, A, B.  But it's missing C. Im not sure why?

Comment: What's the value of `preFilteredRows` in this case?

Comment: preFilteredRows are the cells and they are: [A,B], [B,C], [A,B,C], [C].  So if I select A in the drop down, it will show me all the cells with an 'A'...same for B and C...

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell So you were able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply reduce your Array into one giant array and convert it into a set.

```js
array = [["A", "B", "C"],[],["A", "C"],["B"],["B", "C"],["C"]]
const all = array.reduce((acc, inner) => acc.concat(inner), []) 
const unique = new Set(all)
console.log(unique)
```

Comment: I can't get this too work because 'option' is not an array, but a "set" in my code above

Comment: Use `array = new Array(options)`